# How to swap rows to columns in such a way?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the current dataset in a dataframe:

[image]

Now I would like to convert it to this way:

[image]

Kindly assist

Comment: What form is this data in? A data frame? A database? Perhaps you would like to post some code for context.

Comment: This is in a dataframe format.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done more straight-forward.

```
df = df.melt("Date", value_name="Strike1").reset_index(drop=True)
df.pop("variable") # delete an additional column that .melt creates

>>> df
           Date  Strike1
    0  1-Jan-20     1000
    1  2-Jan-20      300
    2  1-Jan-20      700
    3  2-Jan-20      896
    4  1-Jan-20      600
    5  2-Jan-20      259
```

If you want to sort by `Date`, you can do this afterwards:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=["Date"]).reset_index(drop=True)
>>> df
           Date  Strike1
    0  1-Jan-20     1000
    1  1-Jan-20      700
    2  1-Jan-20      600
    3  2-Jan-20      300
    4  2-Jan-20      896
    5  2-Jan-20      259
```

`.reset_index()` is used to avoid having an unordered index as a result of the new ordering given to the dataframe. It is totally optional and you may or may not want this, depending on what you're doing this for.

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> pd.Series(df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith("strike")].values.tolist(),
              index=df["Date"], 
              name="Strike").explode().to_frame().reset_index()

       Date Strike
0  2020-1-1   1000
1  2020-1-1    700
2  2020-1-1    600
3  2020-1-2    300
4  2020-1-2    896
5  2020-1-2    259
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

With [set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas-dataframe-set-index) and [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas-dataframe-stack):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['1-Jan-20', '2-Jan-20'],
                   'strike1': [1000, 300],
                   'strike2': [700, 896],
                   'strike3': [600, 259]})

out = df.set_index('Date').stack().droplevel(1, 0).reset_index(name='Strike')
print(out)
```

`out`:

```
       Date  Strike
0  1-Jan-20    1000
1  1-Jan-20     700
2  1-Jan-20     600
3  2-Jan-20     300
4  2-Jan-20     896
5  2-Jan-20     259
```